Tally Voucher - import single voucher in html format
So in nodejs im trying to import a single Voucher in tally based on the voucher number.
I am able to get the information of the single voucher in xml format..
But i need to get in HTML format so that i will convert it to pdf buffer and send to frontend to download.
This is the XML code im using to get VOUCHER
<ENVELOPE>
    <HEADER>
        <VERSION>1</VERSION>
        <TALLYREQUEST>EXPORT DATA</TALLYREQUEST>
        <TYPE>Object</TYPE>
        <SUBTYPE>VOUCHER</SUBTYPE>
        <ID TYPE="Name">Date:'20240701':VoucherNumber:'SS/0'</ID>
        </HEADER>
        <BODY>
        <DESC>
        <STATICVARIABLES>
        <SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName:HTML</SVEXPORTFORMAT>
        <SVVIEWNAME>Accounting Voucher View</SVVIEWNAME>  
        <SVCURRENTCOMPANY>comp name</SVCURRENTCOMPANY>
        </STATICVARIABLES>
          <REPORTNAME>Voucher Register</REPORTNAME>
            <FETCHLIST>
                <FETCH>Date</FETCH>
                <FETCH>VoucherNumber</FETCH>
                <FETCH>VoucherTypeName</FETCH>
            </FETCHLIST>
        </DESC>
    </BODY>
</ENVELOPE>

Is there any way to dorectly extract the pdf of the accounting voucher form tally itself??
I tried everything till TDLs and still no solution to get the single voucher as how we see in Accounting Voucher view and get the pdf of the voucher.

Downloading in xml will be less characters than pdf.  It is better to convert to pdf after the download.

There is no need to convert HTML to a PDF format; you may directly upload the PDF file to the server.
$$MakeHTTPName : <HttpUrl>: <HttpIsSecure>: <HttpUserName>: <HttpPassword>: <CompanyName>

More details
